# Prove that for all n $(-1)^1[nC1(1+rln10)/(1+ln10^n)^r1] +(-1)^2[nC2(1+rln10)/(1+ln10^n)^r]+....=0 $

Tags: binomial-theorem

Prove that for  nbelongs to natural number

$$(-1)^1{n\choose1}\dfrac{(1+r\ln10)}{(1+\ln(10^n))^r} +(-1)^2{n\choose2}\dfrac{(1+r\ln10)}{(1+\ln(10^n))^r}+....=0 $$

I have proved this by induction which clearly is not the method

Comment: There are some typos in your question please take a look and edit it.

Comment: I think the question is now properly editted

Comment: For $n=1$, the LHS is equal to $-\frac{1+r\ln{10}}{(1+\ln{10})^r}$ which is not $0$ in general.

Comment: i have editted the question again

Comment: the series goes on and on...we are not dealing with cases here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the binomial theorem $$(1+x)^n = 1 + \binom{n}{1} x + ... \binom{n}{n} x^n$$

But $x = -1$, we obtain:

$$(-1)^0{n\choose0}+(-1)^1{n\choose1} +(-1)^2{n\choose2}+... (-1)^n{n\choose n} =0$$

Therefore your series evaluates to $-\frac{1+r\ln{10}}{(1+\ln{10})^r}$ for all $n$ (Naturals).

Comment: can you elaborate here

Comment: Take $\frac{1+r\ln{10}}{(1+\ln{10})^r}$ common from all terms first. Then you get the series written in the answer, but one term $(-1)^0 \binom{n}{0}$ is missing. So we add and subtract it. You can ask if you still didn't understand!

Comment: Can u show your workout please in an answer?:)

Comment: Can u show your workout please in an answer?:

Comment: I am so sorry dear didnt read comment. All I can say is take that whole expression common and you will see the result.